# Greedy execution of statements?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have something like this using BeautifulSoup:

```
for line in lines:
    code = l.find('span', {'class':'boldHeader'}).text
    coded = l.find('div', {'class':'Description'}).text
    definition = l.find('ul', {'class':'definitions'}).text
    print code, coded, def
```

However, not all elements exist at all times. I can enclose this in a try except so that it does not break the program execution like this:

```
for line in lines:
    try:
      code = l.find('span', {'class':'boldHeader'}).text
      coded = l.find('div', {'class':'Description'}).text
      definition = l.find('ul', {'class':'definitions'}).text
      print code, coded, def
    except:
      pass
```

But how I execute the statements in a greedy fashion? For instance, if there are only two elements available `code` and `coded`, I just want to get those and continue with the execution. As of now, even if `code` and `coded` exist, if `def` does not exist, the print command is never executed.

One way of doing this is to put a `try...except` for every statement like this:

```
for line in lines:
    try:
      code = l.find('span', {'class':'boldHeader'}).text
    except:
      pass
    try:
      coded = l.find('div', {'class':'Description'}).text
    except:
      pass
    try:
      definition = l.find('ul', {'class':'definitions'}).text
    except:
      pass
    print code, coded, def
```

But this is an ugly approach and I want something cleaner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about capture the "ugly" code in a function, and just call the function as needed:

```
def get_txt(l,tag,classname):
    try:
        txt=l.find(tag, {'class':classname}).text
    except AttributeError:
        txt=None
    return txt

for line in lines:
    code = get_txt(l,'span','boldHeader')
    coded = get_txt(l,'div','Description')
    defn = get_txt(l,'ul','definitions')
    print code, coded, defn
```

PS. I changed `def` to `defn` because `def` is a Python keyword. Using it as a variable name raises a SyntaxError.

PPS. It's not a good practice to use bare exceptions:

```
try:
    ....
except:
    ...
```

because it almost always captures more that you intend. Much better to be explicit about what you want to catch:

```
try:
    ...
except AttributeError as err:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. +1 for a detailed description. Lesson learnt :)

Comment: Nice answer. Using try/catch as part of the 'normal' program flow might not be favorable.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can test for None instead of catching an exception. `l.find` should return `None` if it doesn't find your item. Exceptions should be reserved for errors and really extraordinary situations.

Second thing you can do is to create an array of all HTML elements you want to check and then have a nested for loop. Since it's been a while since I've used python, I will outline the code and then (hopefully) edit the answer when I test it.

Something like:

```
elementsToCheck = [
                  [ 'span', {'class':'boldHeader'} ],
                  [ 'div', {'class':'Description'} ],
                  [ 'ul', {'class':'definitions'} ]]

concatenated = ''
for line in lines:
    for something in elementsToCheck
       element = l.find(something[0], something[1])
       if element is not None
          concatenated += element.text
print concatenated
```

Obviously the code above won't work, but you should get the idea. :)

Comment: Thanks I am looking into this now. But one question is that `find` actually throws an exception which is the main reason I started using a `try...catch` block. So in the new approach, if `find` throws an exception, won't it come out of the `for loop`?

Comment: Or maybe I will put a `try...catch` inside the for loop. I will get back. +1 for your time. Thanks

Comment: @Legend: Oh, if it throws then you will need to catch. I would nevertheless check that it doesn't actually throw a null-reference exception because you are calling `.text` on an empty object (that would seem more logical, but again, I don't use python that much to know its best practices).

Comment: So I checked this approach as well. It works perfectly fine :) @Paul McGuire: I didn't know anyone noticed such small things. I guess that's the least I could do for the knowledge I'm gaining here :)